# Cannot invoke 'methodName' with an argument list of type

Tags: swift, generics

I couldn't get the point of this compiler's error message
"Cannot invoke 'getValueType' with an argument list of type '(value: T)'
for the line "if (CMFStream.getValueType(value: test) != type) {"

```
public func readArray<T>() -> Array<T>
{
    // ...
    var retval: Array<T>;
    let test: T;
    if (CMFStream.getValueType(value: test) != type) {
    // ...
    }
}
```

I guess that I don't understand the difference between generics and templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an object of type `T` to `getValueType`.  `T` is an unconstrained generic type, which means that at compile time it could be any type known in the scope. It has a definite type, but the compiler doesn't know what that type is. `T` is a placeholder for it.

When it encounters the line that invokes `getValueType` with an argument of type `T` it looks for a way to satisfy that.  the error you see says that it didn't find a way to do that.

Here's a minimal example:

```
func foo<U>(f:U) {
    bar(b:f)
}

func bar(b:Int) {
}
```

This fails because bar accepts an Int, but foo could pass it any type.

There are two ways to fix this.

**Method 1**

Make bar generic:

```
func bar<V>(b:V) {
}
```

so if you call

```
foo(f:1)
```

The compiler replaces `U` with `Int`, creating:

```
func foo(f:Int) {
    bar(b:f)
}
```

Now it needs a bar that accepts an `Int`, so it replaces `V` with `Int` to give

```
func bar(b:Int) {
}
```

Now the types are consistent so it can proceed.

**Method 2**

Constrain `U`:

```
protocol P {}

func foo<U:P>(f:U) {
    bar(b:f)
}
```

This says that `U` is any type that conforms to the protocol `P`.  So now we can define `bar` like this:

```
func bar(b:P) {
}
```

This defines a `bar` that accepts anything that conforms to protocol `P`.

Now whatever the placeholder `U` is replaced with, the compiler knows that it conforms to `P`, and it can always find a `bar` that accepts something that conforms to `P`.  The compiler can proceed.